# php access json_decode data

Tags: php, json

this is my json object

```
object(stdClass)#23 (2) { ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["$t"]=> string(10) "cippalippa" }
```

How can I access to `"text" ["$t"]` ?

Comment: What are you wanting access to?  `'text'` or `[$t]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this string:
    $obj->{'$t'}

Answer (score 5):

You need to use this syntax:

```
$object->{'$t'}
```

The other two that were mentioned here don’t work as:

- <del>`$object["\$t"]`</del> – an object is not an array
- <del>`$objetct->$t`</del> – this would be interpreted as a [variable variable](http://php.net/language.variables.variable):

  > […] if you have an expression such as `$foo->$bar`, then the local scope will be examined for `$bar` and its value will be used as the name of the property of `$foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dollar sign:

```
echo $object["\$t"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$object = json_decode({ ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["$t"]=> string(10) "cippalippa" });

echo $objetct->$t;
```

Is this working?